# Trouble adjusting content with css

Tags: css

[my pages content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn7wH.png)

I am working on my project and i want to make it responsive and i am having problem adjusting the position of each element.So far i have been trying to adjust them with media queries and with margins like the example below but i think they are interfering with each other and some times they dont move at all.Whats the best way to approach something like this?

css:

```
.slider-wrapper {
    
    text-align: center;
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  .slider-wrapper .slider {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(370px) translateX(50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 15px;
    appearance: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000dca, #56608fb4, pink, #eeec90, #94ffa2);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
   
    
  }
  
  .slider-wrapper .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
   
    
  }

  .slider-wrapper p {
  
    font-size: 40px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  
  #sliderValue {
    font-weight: bold
    
  }


.feelingText {
    display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  
  
}
.updatedText {
    font-size: 30px; 
    
}
.textarea-title{
 
    font-size: 20px;
  
  
}

.moreFeelings{

    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
}


@media (max-width: 1500px) {

.svg-container{
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
  .slider-container{
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
   
    .feelingText{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 350px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

    .textarea-title{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        
        margin-bottom: 10px auto;
        margin-left: 20px;
      
      }

    .moreFeelings{
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        height: 4em;
        width: 15em;
    }

    .slider-wrapper p {
      max-width: 95%; 
      
       
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 25px;
     
    }

    .slider-wrapper .slider {
      transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(370px) translateX(50%);
      width: 400px;
      height: 15px;
      appearance: none;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #000dca, #56608fb4, pink, #eeec90, #94ffa2);
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 100px;


}
}




@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .slider-wrapper .slider {
    
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
   
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-top: 120px;

}

  .svg-container{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 500px;
  }
 
.feelingText {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 190px;
    
      
}

.textarea-title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  }
  
  .moreFeelings{
      margin-left: 25vh;
      margin-top: 5px;
      height: 4em;
      width: 25em;
  
  }
  .slider-wrapper p {
    max-width: 90%; 
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 15px;
   
   
  }
  
}
.slider-wrapper .slider {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(370px) translateX(50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 15px;
    appearance: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000dca, #56608fb4, pink, #eeec90, #94ffa2);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
   
    
  }
  
  .slider-wrapper .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
   
    
  }

  .slider-wrapper p {
  
    font-size: 40px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  
  #sliderValue {
    font-weight: bold
    
  }


.feelingText {
    display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  
  
}
.updatedText {
    font-size: 30px; 
    
}
.textarea-title{
 
    font-size: 20px;
  
  
}

.moreFeelings{

    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making the sizing and positioning relative to the viewport dimension (possibtle vmin in this case as you have a circle) rather than fixing them with px?

Comment: is it wrong adjusting it with margins and px? Because i have a hard time making it work

Comment: It's not intrinsically 'wrong' to use px, but I suggested looking into using units that relate to the viewport size as a way of getting to a responsive site.

Comment: If use use px will there be the same for the different viewports?

Comment: It may help you to read about some techniques for responsive implementations E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design